# Ver qual usuário criou ou alterou um Linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, segurança

Senhores,

Como auditar a criação ou alteração de Linked Servers no SQL Server 2008 ou superior? (Ver quem criou ou alterou um linked server).

Comment: Um ponto de partida está aqui: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645889(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Valeu Cigano, vou dar uma olhada.